# Evaluating $\int \frac {1}{1-a\sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could anyone evaluate the $\int \dfrac {1}{1-a\sin x}dx$? If $a=-1$, then I can evaluate it, but in general what can I do?

Comment: Ok, I corrected it.

Comment: Try using $t=\tan(\frac x2)$ , the tangent half-angle substitution; it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments;

Let $t:=\tan {\frac{x}{2}},\; \mathrm{d}t=\frac12 \sec ^2 \frac{x}{2}$

Then $\sin x=\dfrac{2t}{t^2+1},\; \cos x=\dfrac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}$

$$I=\int \frac{1}{1-a\sin x}\;\mathrm{d}x=2\int \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(t^2+1)\left (1-\frac{2at}{t^2+1}\right )}$$

The rest are pretty straightforward.